# Backpack For Laravel with Laravel Vapor - worthwhile or a headache?

Tags: laravel-backpack, laravel-vapor

I've spent the last day learning vapor and have got my backpack install live.

Though first thing i see is a dead image of the logo as it's within the backpack config file so we can't use the asset() helper.

Simple enough to duplicate the view, but how many more little things are there to worry about with going down this path of vapor or should i do a 180 and set up Elastic Beanstalk?

Is there an optimal way to deploy backpack on vapor, its hard to find much info related to it thats recent.

Also will backpack 4.2 include any vapor support?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/2118) for Backpack trying to provide official Laravel Vapor support. The current solutions are mentioned at the bottom of the thread:

- (A) [this 7-step how-to guide](https://gist.github.com/tabacitu/2617674467fc1fc9aaa23073ba34e035) (needs workarounds)
- (B) [docker-based deployments](https://blog.laravel.com/vapor-docker-based-deployments) (probably better, but haven't tested)

Please leave feedback in [the thread](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/2118) or [gist](https://gist.github.com/tabacitu/2617674467fc1fc9aaa23073ba34e035) - it will help make this process better for everyone else trying to deploy Backpack on Vapor.